# Unable to write to SQL Server even when using parameters

Tags: python, sql, pyodbc

The SQL Server has these properties.

I want to write df to a SQL Server table but I get an error "table does not exist".

[image: Code]

What am I doing wrong?

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=DESKTOP-FCBC9GE/NEW_INSTANCE;'
                      'Database=master;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM df')
```

[image: The SQL Server and the pyodbc connect parameters are the same]

Comment: The error message in your screenshot there is that the SQL Server inaccessible. Can you connect to it with any other tools?

Comment: Also, `df` appears to be one of your objects in python, and not a database table? Did you mean `Chelsea` like your screenshot suggests? Your select statement (which isn't being executed at the moment) is trying to run that on the master database. I would advise against using the master database for anything as the server uses that. Much more advisable to make your own database.

Comment: @LordBaconPants I havent tried connecting it with any other yet.
Yes, I mean Chelsea as the screenshot says. Where do I run the select statement?

Comment: @LordBaconPants could you please help with the code? This inn instance is just one of the URL. I would like to have a list of url files e.g. 'https://www.soccerbase.com/teams/team.sd?team_id=536&comp_id=1&teamTabs=results' for Chelsea and 'https://www.soccerbase.com/teams/team.sd?team_id=142&comp_id=1&teamTabs=results' for Arsenal and such. Not limited just to the EPL.. This would then write to their individual tables in the mentioned above SQL server. Could you please help with the code?

Comment: That is a bit out of scope for StackOverflow, and I'm just an SQL guy I'm afraid. It would be blind leading the blind :)

Comment: The error message doesn't mention tables, it says "SQL Server does not exist.." - this is a _connection_ error i.e. your connection to SQL Server is not working. There could be a number of explanations for this, e.g. SQL Server service is not running, is not configured to allow trusted connections, is being blocked by a firewall or security software...

Comment: Hi @NathanGriffiths My server is on my local machine. The error I get is 'df.to_sql('Chelsea', con=pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied. (17) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen (Connect()). (67)')'

Comment: Firstly I would avoid using the [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver] driver that comes with Windows, that thing is ancient. Download and install the latest SQL Server ODBC driver (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) then change `Driver={SQL Server}` to `Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}`. This might not solve your issue but it will rule out any causes that might be due to using a very old ODBC driver.

Comment: @LordBaconPants can we connect? I really need help with this. my email address is harshadbarge@gmail.com

Comment: @NathanGriffiths I Did! And the error I get now is a bit different. Any pointers in how I can overcome this? [linl](https://imgur.com/63FmTZG) `df.to_sql('Chelsea', con=pyodbc.connect('Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};'
                                        'Server=DESKTOP-FCBC9GE/NEW_INSTANCE;'
                                        'Database=master;'
                                        'trusted_connection=yes'),
          if_exists='append')
df.execute('SELECT * FROM df').fetchall()`

Comment: @NathanGriffiths Error: `df.to_sql('Chelsea', con=pyodbc.connect('Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};'
pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [67].  (67) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is corre....
`

Comment: The way you specify a SQL Server instance with a specific instance should be with a **backslash** - not a forward slash. So instead of `Server=DESKTOP-FCBC9GE/NEW_INSTANCE` try using `Server=DESKTOP-FCBC9GE\NEW_INSTANCE`

Comment: Hey @marc_s when I do the backslash.. it gives me a syntax error: [link] (https://imgur.com/w5ul8Dj)